# Apache Curator GroupMember how to get complete set of members?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am very new to Zookeeper so I am trying to use Curator recipes to see if I can get my pretty simple asks out of the box.

I am trying to use Curator GroupMember class/recipe in order to split workload between nodes. GroupMember start() method javadoc says "begin caching all members" - how do I request or get a notification once all members are received?

Kind of a follow-up: I've notices that sometimes my groupMember.setData() invocation throws "initial create has not been processed. Call waitForInitialCreate() to ensure" which is on PersistentNode which is not even exposed by MemberGroup.

Looks like I am really missing something about MemberGroup API :(

Answer (score 0):

The caching in Curator uses the concept of "eventual consistency" - meaning that the values you get will just be whatever happens to be in the cache at the time. It is pretty good at staying up-to-date; it just doesn't guarantee that what you get will be the latest values.

In this case, "begin caching all members" just means that before the call to the `start` method there was no caching happening; and after the call caching will happen. It doesn't mean that you have to wait for caching to complete before you can use it, or anything like that.